# Can a laundry sink drain be moved downstream of an existing vent?

Tags: plumbing, venting

**Context**:
I am located in California and doing an addition and moving the kitchen.

The kitchen sink and dishwasher drain into an existing line in the garage that has a laundry sink and a clothes washer.

I need advice on venting, pipe size, moving the laundry sink and clothes washer.

Existing - Garage has a laundry sink and clothes washer on a 2in drain with a 1.5 in vent. Note the clothes washer is downstream of the vent. The laundry sink is upstream.

New - Adding a Kitchen Sink and Dishwasher in the Kitchen with a 2in pipe flowing into an existing garage line with laundry and clothes washer. Adding a 1.5in vent in the kitchen. Moving clothes washer upstream of the existing 1.5 in vent, moving laundry sink downstream of the existing vent.

**Questions**:

1. Can the Laundry Sink be moved downstream of the existing vent and the clothes washer be moved upstream of the existing vent? See diagram
2. How long can the Laundry sink arm
   be? 1.5in drain to 1.5in vent. 5ft?
3. The existing 2” PVC drain to crawlspace does not have a vent. As the arm is over 13ft long, does it need a new vent?
4. Is 2" PVC pipe drain to crawlspace big enough for Kitchen Sink, Dishwasher, Clothes washer, and Laundry Sink?
5. Is the existing 1.5” Vent large enough for Kitchen Sink, Dishwasher, Clothes washer, and Laundry Sink?

See diagrams - Notice the difference between existing and new.

[image: Existing Garage Piping]

[image: Proposed New Piping Setup]

[image: New V2 - based on Ecnerwal feedback]

[image: New V3 - based on Ecnerwal feedback]

Comment: What plumbing code is in effect for where you are?

Comment: @Ecnerwal 2019 California Plumbing Code
Based on the 2018 Uniform Plumbing Code

Comment: The "new" laundry as sketched has several issues, which are probably sketch issues - You've drawn an S-trap on the standpipe, and you have the 2" line form the kitchen connecting to the 1.5" exsisting vent as a drain.

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Answer (score 0):

For International Plumbing code you would have:

- Automatic clothes washer residential - 2 DFUs
- Kitchen Sink, with dishwasher or food disposal or both - 2 DFUs
- Service Sink (or Laundry Tray) -  2 DFUs

6 DFUs total. The Automatic clothes washer calls for 2" minimum drain

You do have a vent on the line to the basement right now. It's the vent at the laundry area.

A properly sloped dry-vented 2" pipe has a capacity of 21 DFUs, as a building drain, but is limited to 6 DFUs for a single horizontal branch. I'm not finding the precise point where they define horizontal branch .vs. horizontal building drain, but it would not matter for 6 DFUs.

*And you've just clarified that you are under UPC, so this answer may not apply to you, and I'm going to leave it hanging here. Or put in a bit more; UPC will be similar, but differ in details, and I don't normally work with it given where I live.*

1-1/2" dry vent on 2" drain is good for 12 DFUs if less than 75 feet or 20 DFUs if less than 50 feet developed length.

1-1/2" drain can be 6 feet long if properly sloped at 1/4" per foot. However, you appear to have drawn connecting a 2" drain to the 1.5" vent as a drain, which would be reducing the size of the drain, and making the 1.5" a wet vent - neither good. You may have meant to increase that lower section where the drains join in "new" to 2" - you need to, whether or not you meant to. 1.5" drain arm to 2" drain with 1.5" vent is fine.

You can only wet-vent 4 DFUs in your 2" drain line; You may not need more than one 1-1/2" dry vent, but you might need to connect it to your drain line at more than one point to limit the extent that the 2" drain is serving as a wet vent.

Comment: Hi @ecnerwal, I have added a new diagram to reflect your feedback. A few follow up points:

Comment: Vents - one 1.5" vent re-vented at multiple points (what is the max arm distance for a re-vent?)

Comment: Does the code permit adding a new re-vent into and exiting vent?

Comment: Vent to Drain - Upgraded 1.5" drain to 2" drain at the base of the Existing Vent.

Comment: P Trap vs S Trap - The existing clothes washer has a S trap. I understand I need to upgrade to P trap. I might not have the space for the kitchen drain and the washer p trap. Can the kitchen drain and the washer p trap be connected before reaching the vent?

Comment: You should be able to Wye the Laundry into the kitchen line, no problem. If dry vent lines are correctly "vertical to 6 inches above the flood rim of the highest fixture on the floor served" and then sloped to drain any condensate back to the drain, there's no practical limit on "arm length" (other than the developed length of the vent) because they are dry. Arm length limits are about pipes with water in them not siphoning. The extra vent to the garage side won't hurt anything, but is probably not needed. Still awaiting a UPC-conversant person pointing out any differences.

Comment: Only issue I'd expect for connection to an existing vent would be if the existing vent was non-compliant and grandfathered, which does not appear likely to be an issue here. Since it's less than 8 feet from the kitchen sink trap weir to a dry vent, and less than 8 feet from the washer standpipe trap weir to a dry vent, the only thing being wet vented is the laundry sink, which at 2 DFUs is only half the wet vent capacity of the 2" drain. That could easily be dry vented as well; put a tee to the vent in its trap arm, for considerably less pipe than the garage side vent I don't think you need.

Comment: That also makes the location of that sink less constrained - if it has a vent connection on the trap arm close enough to the trap weir, the trap arm length beyond the vent connection is unlimited, other than by required slope.

Comment: Thank you @Ecnerwal.     New V3 -  Based on Feedback received. See comments below.

Comment: Vents - one 1.5" vent - re-vented Kitchen Vent to Existing 1.5” Vent to Roof in garage. One challenge is that the Existing 1.5” Vent to Roof is in wall, and comes out of the wall at the connection with the Existing Laundry Drain close to the floor line (16in). I will have to modify the Existing 1.5” Vent to Roof, so that the New Re-Vent for Laundry connects to it.

Comment: Kitchen Drain - Added a rough 7” drop at Kitchen Vent location to accommodate change in elevation between Kitchen and Garage. Is it code to add a step at the bottom of the New Re-vent?

Comment: Clothes washer - Wye washer P trap to Kitchen drain upstream of Existing 1.5” Vent to Roof.    -    Does the plane of the wye have to be slightly angled up (rotated up), or can it be perfectly aligned with the slop of the Kitchen drain?

Comment: Garage 2” drain - I am not clear on why the garage drain does not need a re-vent? Is it because the wet vent capacity of a 2in pipe is 4 DFU and with the following V3 setup, no fixtures is being wet vented?

Comment: **Vents are about protecting trap seals.** So, if the trap seals are protected by the vents serving them, the drain line after that point does not require further venting - those vents also vent that line. If the line fills completely and starts suction, air comes in the vents, and not through the traps.

Comment: Got it. So vents are only needed on a line with a trap, that is not getting any air. Because the 2" drain the garage is connected to a vent, from which it is getting air, the 2" garage drain does not need to be vented further down the line.

Comment: Then, Does the slope requirement to vent to prevent siphoning only apply to lines with traps?